# gwt + spring security

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-security

I use gwt requestBuilder to query server result, if server-side spring
checked user is not authenticated, it will forward to

```
 <form-login
login-page="/gwtapplication.html#!login"
```

, but gwt is not
forwarded to that page.  see below

```
requestBuilder.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onError(final Request request, final Throwable
exception) {
                resultCallback.onFailure(exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(final Request request,
                    final Response response) {

                if(response.getHeader("Content-
Type").toLowerCase().equals("text/html".toLowerCase()))
                {

                //response.getText() is
                /**
                  Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
                  Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=1emk892yva1e9;Path=/
                  Location http://127.0.0.1:8888/gwtapplication.html#!login
                 Content-Length 0
                 Server Jetty(6.1.x)

               **/

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly what you are trying to do but it looks like you want to forward the login to your gwt applications: `gwtapplication.html` and then let the gwt history manager load the login page with anchor: `!login`? If you directly go to `/gwtapplication.html#!login` do you get the login page?

Comment: @Hibrand, yes, if i go directly, i can go there. i modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call RequestBuilder performs is intecepted by spring security and redirected to the authentication page instead of the `normal` result. Because RequestBuilder is not asking for a new version of your GWT page, but a `separate` page, this has no effect on redirecting your GWT page. Just like an image would be retrieved in the `src` tag, which instead of the image returned the authentication page would be returned. If you want to redirect upon RequestBuilder results you would have to do this in GWT by yourself, by setting a new HistoryItem to the `!login` token.